# How to Convert List<Map<String, Object>> to List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java

I am retrieving results from DB Query as `List<Map<String, Object>>` format, can you suggest, How to convert it to `List<Map<String, String>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for-each iteration over the list items and its map entries does the trick:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = ...
List<Map<String, String>> newList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map<String, Object> map: list) {
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()); // mapping happens here
    }
    newList.add(newMap);
}
```

In my opinion, this is the optimal solution and the most readable solution. The [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) is not suitable much for working with dictionaries (although you always get a collection from it).

Comment: Awesome, your solution worked flawless - you save my day.

Comment: Welcome. As long as you are new here, let me suggest you consider marking the best answer as accepted (green tick) (up to your choice) and eventually upvote (this action is optional, it's like saying "thank you, it helps"). The acceptance is an indicator that this issue has been resolved for the future incomers.

Comment: @Nikolas what do you mean "The java-stream is  not suitable much for working with dictionaries"?

Comment: Aside: `map.forEach((k, v) -> newMap.put(k, v.toString()));` is a neater way to do the inner-most loop: having to deal with map entries always feels gross.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate the list, transforming each of the maps in turn:

```
list.stream()
    .map(map ->
        map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().toString())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, you save my day.